# Why doesn't this singleton concept produce an infinite loop?

Tags: python, singleton, infinite-loop

I found this searching for singleton concepts in Python. What I wonder about is why `self._instance = super(Singleton, self).__new__(self)`doesn't cause an infinte loop. I thought that calling `__new__` would start a kind of recursion, as `self._instance`should not have been set then.

Where's my mistake?

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(self):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(Singleton, self).__new__(self)
        return self._instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
super(Singleton, self).__new__(self)
```

means: call `__new__` on the superclass of `Singleton` (which is `object`).

So it won't call the same `__new__` again and as such it won't create an infinite loop.

After returning it'll set `self._instance` to a value. Next time you call `Singleton()` it'll return that instance instead.

Answer (score 3):

This, actually, calls `object.__new__`, not the `Singleton.__new__`, so there is no recursion.

Comment: Isn't `Singleton.__new__()` supposed to return an instance of `Singleton`? But as you mentioned, you get an instance of `object` when you do `super(Singleton, self).__new__(self)`